# Link error when compiling sample opencv kalman filter program

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, linker

I am currently trying to build and run the kalman filter example program found on https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d70/samples_2cpp_2kalman_8cpp-example.html#a12

When I try to compile the program, I get the following output:

```
g++ -o  kalman kalman.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_objdetect
/usr/bin/ld: kalman.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv12KalmanFilter7predictERKNS_3MatE'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: kalman] Error 1
```

I seem to be missing a link library in my Makefile, but I have looked everywhere online and I can't seem to find it.

I have tried switching the order of the link libraries in the LIBS variable of my Makefile. I first tried putting -lopencv_tracking (where I assume the kalman filter functions are) at the end of the link list, and then I tried putting it second in the list (right in front of -lopencv_core). Both yielded the same link error.

Here is the Makefile that I am using

```
CC=g++
TARGET=kalman
SRC=kalman.cpp
LIBS=-lopencv_core -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_objdetect
OBJ=kalman.o
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
kalman: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o  $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

The program should build correctly with no errors

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, I was missing -lopencv_video in my LIBS